# rewriting spider in OOP terms

Tags: python, oop, web-crawler

Hope everyone is well

So I wrote some code for a spider not long ago and it was for a website that shows house prices and sale dates in London. I have recently decided to improve it by making it object oriented.

The scope of the spider extends to 680 areas such as one given by this link:

http://www.rightmove.co.uk/house-prices/St-Johns-Wood.html

and if you click on the page, you will see that there are 40 pages for each area.

The reason that I would like to do OOP on this is because I need to involve a few methods that deal with updating the database that it saves to, so I do not have to run the whole spider again.

My first question is this: is it better to abstract the individual pages and treat them as an object or to treat each of the 680 areas as an object and involve methods to crawl each of the 40 pages for one area?

My second question is this: 
Would someone be kind enough to show me the way that this would be implemented in OOP terms given the answer to the first question?

Below I provide code for the two jobs:

```
def forty_page_getter(link):

    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.get(link)
    html = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    link_box = soup.find('div', {'id':'sliderBottom'})

    rest = link_box.find_all('a')
    links = []
    for i in rest:
        try:
            link = i.get('href')
            links.append(link)
        except:
            pass
    return links

def page_stripper(link):

    '''this function strips all the information on houses and transactions from a page ,
    ready for entry into the database, now make a function for the database '''

    myopener = MyOpener()
    page = myopener.open(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    houses = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'soldDetails'})

    for house in houses:

        try:
            address = house.a.text

        except:
            address = house.find('div',{'class': 'soldAddress'}).text


        postcode_list = address.split()[-2:]
        postcode = postcode_list[0] + ' ' + postcode_list[1]

        table = house.find('table').find_all('tr')

        bedrooms = table[0].find('td', {'class': 'noBed'}).text

        if not bedrooms:
            bedrooms = '0'
        else:
            bedrooms = bedrooms[0]

        house_key = save_house_to_db(address=address, postcode=postcode, bedrooms=bedrooms)

        for row in table[::-1]:
            price = row.find('td', {'class': 'soldPrice'}).text
            date  = row.find('td', {'class': 'soldDate'}).text

            save_transactions_to_db(id = house_key, date= date, sale_price= price)
        print('saved %s to DB' %str(address))
```

I am somewhat confused, if we were to treat the page or even the area link as an object how it would work given that we use BeautifulSoup and selenium for the dynamic updating scrollbar for the forty pages which in themselves are objects.

for example, I was considering the two following ways:

```
class area(BeautifulSoup):

    def __init__(self, html_code):

    def get_all_pages(self):

    def strip_all_pages(self):


#OR would it be better to do this?
class page(object):

    def __init__(self, html_code):

    def strip(self):
```

but I am new to classes and was wondering how to work with Bs4, potentially another library called selenium and making sure that works within my own defined class.

Thanks for any help guys. I appreciate it.

Comment: Very interesting question, indeed... (+1)

Comment: Very interesting question, I'll try to answer it once I'm home.